# How can i access JavaScript constructor object as an IFFI function parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Method 1: `(Successful)` I have an object constructor named Person, inside this object constructor i have used an IFFI function expression that is working properly. Inside this function property of Person is Accessible! But,

```js
var Person = function (age) {
  this.age = age;
  this.retiredIn = (function (obj) {
    return 65 - obj.age;
  })(this);
};

var turna = new Person(22);

console.log(turna);
```

[image]

Method 2: `(I want this, Unsuccessful)` Here is another one i want to do, i Want to insert `retiredIn` function from prototype like this, In this case `this` mentioning the `window` object. How can i access `Person` object from there? I have tried passing Object Directly to the `IFFI` but its not working.

```js
var Person = function (age) {
  this.age = age;
};

Person.prototype.retiredIn = (function () {
  return 65 - this.age; //how can i access Person Object here
})();
var turna = new Person(22);

console.log(turna);
```

[image]

Method 2.1: `(I have tried Like This)` I have passed the Person Contractor directly but its not working!

```js
var Person = function (age) {
  this.age = age;
};

Person.prototype.retiredIn = (function (obj) {
  return 65 - obj.age; //this is also showing NaN
})(Person);
var turna = new Person(22);

console.log(turna);
```

This is also returning NaN.
Is there any way to do this operation like Method 2?

Comment: If i have create 10 object then i have to call that function 10 times thats why i am using iffi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the method a *getter* instead:

```js
var Person = function (age) {
  this.age = age;
};
Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, 'retiredIn', {
  enumerable: true,
  get() {
    return 65 - this.age;
  }
});
var turna = new Person(22);

console.log(turna);
```

Comment: (method) PropertyDescriptor.get?(): any
Missing property name. (E035)jshint(E035)
Peek Problem (Alt+F8)
No quick fixes available Showing this error on get()

Comment: That's a linting error from an ancient linter - consider upgrading to something that *at least* supports ES2015 syntax. The code works fine on any environment that isn't extremely ancient.

Comment: Try ESLint - that's the most widely used linter by far, and it supports modern syntax.

Comment: Its working, i just want to know again that, what practice is good? Method 1 or Method 2(Your Solution)? Is there any possible code repeating? or Memory loss for method 1?

Comment: With my method, the method is on the *prototype* - it's shared between all instances. It's not created anew each time the object is created. so it's a bit more efficient.

Comment: var Person = function (age) {
  this.age = age;
};
Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "retiredIn", "daysCount", {
  enumerable: true,
  get() {
    return 65 - this.age;
  },
  get() {
    return this.age * 365;
  },
});
var turna = new Person(22);

console.log(turna.daysCount); How can i use multiple function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212917/discussion-between-moniruzzaman-monir-and-certainperformance).